# yocto layers required to build imx8mp-evk with netdata

Tags: yocto, yocto-recipe, yocto-layer

I am new bee for imx8mp-evk yocto build, need to understand which all layers required to build imx8mp-evk yocto build with netdata, I want to get netdata metrics with minimal imx8mp-evk image that can provide netdata metrics. Please do suggest the list of layers required.

Thanks for any help,
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

You can browse https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/ to find more info about layers and recipes.

If you go to the `Machines` tab and search for `imx8`, you can find devices such as `imx8mp-ddr4-evk`, you'll have to find which exact device you need. Sometimes your specific machine won't be there but the appropriate family of machines might be. It look's like [meta-freescale](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-freescale/) would be the layer you would be interested in.

Then going back to the layer index, if you search under recipes you can find `netdata` is provided by [meta-webserver](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/recipe/50696/).

So you would need:

- meta-freescale
- meta-webserver

And their dependencies

- meta-oe
- openembedded-core

And probably some sort of Distro layer e.g. use `poky` but add the above layers. See the [Yocto quick build](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html) reference on how to get started.